# mod_rewrite not working as it should

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite URLs as follows:

- www.example.com/module-name(/) => handler.php?module=module-name
- www.example.com/module-name/list/of/arguments(/) => handler.php?module=module-name&args=list/of/arguments (which I explode later in the script)

If module-name is missing or not allowed, it loads the home page of the website. No problems here.
The problem is that mod_rewrite isn't working as it should. I wrote these rewrite rules...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$     handler.php?module=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)/?$    handler.php?module=$1&args=$2
```

...but instead of passing **module-name** as *module* to the handler, the rewrite engine passes the name of the script itself, **handler.php**. I tried with different regex in the last two days, but the result is always the same. I don't know what to do anymore!
The rewrite rules are inside an .htaccess, placed in the document root (together with handler.php), and I'm running xampp on an Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit machine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, after rewrite occurs, it goes to next cycle instead of existing immediately as you would expect.

You need to alter your rule (or add separate condition) to ignore requests to `handler.php` file. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!handler\.php)([^/]*)/?$ handler.php?module=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(?!handler\.php)([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ handler.php?module=$1&args=$2 [L]
```

or with extra separate condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/handler\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ handler.php?module=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/handler\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ handler.php?module=$1&args=$2 [L]
```

or even like that:

```
# do not touch requests to handler.php
RewriteRule ^handler\.php$ - [L]

# our rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ handler.php?module=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ handler.php?module=$1&args=$2 [L]
```

You can also go even this way (it really depends on your rewriting logic)

```
# do not do anything for requests to existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# our rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ handler.php?module=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ handler.php?module=$1&args=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your fast and detailed answer, now it works like a charm!

Comment: @Ceppo Glad it worked for you. Now please select one of the answers and mark it as Accepted, thnx

Comment: Done. Sorry, I haven't used StackOverflow before :)

Answer (score 1):

A problem could be that existing file-names get rewritten as well. To avoid that, you can add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   # ignore existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   # ignore existing directories
```

So for you it would be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   # ignore existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   # ignore existing directories
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$     handler.php?module=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   # ignore existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   # ignore existing directories
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)/?$    handler.php?module=$1&args=$2
```

Comment: Thank you too for your answer!